# What is the name of the corrispondent event 'got focus', on GTK sharp?

Tags: .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

what is the name of the event fired on GTK sharp when a window got focus ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, ***FocusIn***?

```
public class FocusTest {

    private static void FocusInHandler (object obj, FocusInEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("focus in");
    }

    private static void FocusOutHandler (object obj, FocusOutEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("focus out");
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Application.Init();

        Window window = new Window("Focus test");
        ...
        window.FocusInEvent += new FocusInEventHandler(FocusInHandler);
        window.FocusOutEvent += new FocusOutEventHandler(FocusOutHandler);
        ...  
        window.ShowAll();
        Application.Run();

    }
}
```